# Purview API - 412 error when doing GET request?

Tags: azure-purview

I have a AWS Lambda Pipeline that makes API calls to the Purview API and has been working fine until yesterday.

The error occasionally I get is as below:

{'requestId': 'xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxx', 'errorCode': 'PreConditionCheckFailed', 'errorMessage': 'Pre-condition check failed. Please fetch latest data from Catalog service and update again. Conflict object ID: xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx'}

Some additional info:

- From some googling, I understand that this might be an error that is described to only pop up from any other API requests other than GET, so not sure why I'm getting this here when I'm only using GET requests
- the API endpoint is: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/get-by-guid
- the API call returns the error when I try to use a GUID for a table's column. But, in the error, the 'conflict object ID' is the GUID for the table
- I rescanned data sources and assets, replaced collections in Purview but still get the same error

Anyone have any ideas why?